# How do I put a folder as an input in a matlab function?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need a matlab function that goes through a folder and processes each file in the folder. I'd like to put, as an input, the folder name and the file name that I need to use to process each file in that folder (subtract one image from all the others in the folder). My function also calculates the SD and mean value of each image. I'd like my function to return me a matrix that shows as many rows as the number of images, with 3 columns that indicate: name, SD and mean value of each image, in order to export it to excel. This is my code so far but I'm really missing something!
thanks so much for your help! I've been working on this for days now!

```
function [m]=nenna(path,t)              %# folder path
path=(path)
files = dir( fullfile(path,'*.jpg') );   %# list all *.xyz files
files = {files.name}';                      %'# file names

data = cell(numel(files),1);%# store file contents

a=zeros(numel(files),3);

for i=1:numel(files)
    fname = fullfile(path,files{i});     %# full path to file
    x=imread(files);
    s=imread(t);
    j=imsubtract(x,s);
    j=double(j);
    u=std(j(:))
    q=mean(j(:))
    a(i)=[files(i);u;q]
end
```

Comment: Sorry I made a mess with the code. :/ I hope you can understand it!

Comment: It's not clear what you actual question is. Your title indicates you don't know how to send a path as an input to a function but you've done it fine in your code. So where are you having trouble?

Comment: For future reference, you can format large chunks of code by putting 4 spaces in front of each line. You can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18375127/revisions) what Nick changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each row in `a` to have a string and two numbers, it should be a cell array:

```
... 
a=[]
for i ...
    ...
    a{i}={files{i} u q};
end
...
```

To get to the filenames you do

```
a{1}{1}
ans=
file1.jpg
```

To get to the numbers you do

```
a{1}{2},a{1}{3}
```

(to get std and mean of file1.jpg, resp.)
Another way to do it is to make `a` a struct array.